# load view via ajax cakephp 2.x

Tags: ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

i want to load a list of items on my view via ajax here is my code on lst.cpt

```
<div id='benpane' class='clearfix'>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  <?php echo $ajax->remoteFunction(array(
    'url'=>array('controller'=>'benefits', 'action'=>'display'),
    'update'=>'benpane',
    'indicator'=>'benIndicator'
  )); ?>
  </script>
</div>
```

here is the lst function in my controller

```
function lst() {
        $this->paginate = array('order' => array('ben_name' => 'ASC'),'conditions' => array($this->Benefit->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs)));
        $benefit = $this->paginate('Benefit');
        $this->set('bens', $benefit);
      }
```

when i try to open the view i get the error

```
Error: Call to a member function remoteFunction() on a non-object   
File: /var/www/hassportal/app/View/Benefits/lst.ctp 
Line: 14
```

what could i be doing wrong?

Comment: shouldnt you be using JSHelper instead ?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that the Ajax Helper has been deprecated (and/or perhaps you are not using cakephp 2.x), you seem to be calling the wrong action:

```
'action'=>'display'
```

should be:

```
'action'=>'lst'
```

Also, I would move the code outside of the DIV that is supposed to be updated with the data coming from that action.

Comment: What has replaced the ajax helper? how can i achieve the same result with the new version?

Comment: You can use the [JsHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html).
E.g.: JsHelper::request
Alternatively there is a [porting for 2.x](http://www.cakephp.4uk.pl/) of the old helper.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$this->Ajax->remoteFunction
```

insited of

```
$ajax->remoteFunction
```

Ex:-

```
<?php echo $this->Ajax->remoteFunction(array(
    'url'=>array('controller'=>'benefits', 'action'=>'display'),
    'update'=>'benpane',
    'indicator'=>'benIndicator'
  )); ?>
```